# Prod build is failing in angular 5 lazy routing

Tags: angular

I implemented lazy loading in angular 5, dev build is working without any errors but prod build is failing with the error **Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined** in vendor.bundle.js.

Following is my routing configuration.

**app.routing.ts:**

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo : "login", pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },    
        { path: '', loadChildren: './lazymodule/lazymodule.module#LazymoduleModule' } 
    ];
```

**lazy.routing.ts:**

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
      {

       path: "", component: MenuComponent,
       children: [
         { path: "android/devices", component: Android},
         {path: "android/reports",component: AReports}
       ],
      }
   ]
```

Comment: Are you sure it's because you're lazy loading a module?

Comment: I am not sure but, in vendor.bundle.js at the line **path.split('/')**  i am getting these error.